Cloudflare queues with slow consumer issues
I'm having problems with my Cloudflare queue consumers. Despite using the different configuration options: (max_batch_timeout=0, max_batch_size=1, delaySeconds=0), my workers take between 5 and 10 seconds on average to consume the next batch.
Can cloudflare queues consume messages in a time on the order of milliseconds?
Thanks in advance
